# Need an R function to get data frames from for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a function giving data frame given year.
yr1995=yr(1995) gives a data frame. Here yr is the function. Now I want to get data frames from year 1993 to 2019.

```
for (i in c(1993:2019)) {
  year=yr(i)

}
```

this code saves the 2019 year only. I want a year-wise data frame with name as "year2019" for 2019, "year2018" for the year 2018 and so on.

Comment: You are overwriting the year variable at each iteration, so only the last value will be saved.

Comment: That's what I want to change but confused about how to save each iteration separately. If possible, give me some code to save iterations separately. Thanks.

Comment: `year = lapply(1993:2019, yr)`

Comment: dww, thanks. This code is giving all the data frames in a single list. Again I need to save it year-wise manually and that's what i'm asking help for . I want the data frames to be saved separately as "Year1995", "year1996".

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to call form the data frame itself something like:

`my_years <- df$years == 1983:1999
df[my_years]`

If you want to use this function try changing

`year` to `year[i]`

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do (dynamic assignment of variable names) is not good practice. Here is an alternative, saving the data frames in a list (as user dww already commented).

```
year = lapply(1993:2019, yr)
```

After that you can change the names of the list elements

```
names(year)=paste0("year",1993:2019)
```